# composer install when Installing setasign/fpdi_pdf-parser

Tags: laravel, composer-php, fpdi

What Username and password need to fill in when process Installing setasign/fpdi_pdf-parser? Thank You

I did process my composer install, but when until Installing setasign/fpdi_pdf-parser, then it stop installing and request me fill me Username & password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The credentials are the same you use to login into your personal account at [setasign.com](https://www.setasign.com/login).

You can also define an alternative password, which you can use for downloads via Composer in your [profile](https://www.setasign.com/my-setasign/profile/):

[image: Optional Composer Password]

Also the given dependency requires a valid license for the FPDI PDF-Parser add-on. But the error message will tell you in case you haven't a valid one (you need at least to be authenticated).

Comment: is there have a way to get a free valid licenses for the FPDI PDF-Parser? or how to skip Installing setasign/fpdi_pdf-parser?

Comment: You can skip the installation by removing it from your composer.json file? We also offer free [evaluation](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/evaluate/) licenses (which requires Ioncube and another dependency in your composer.json - details are available in your personal pickup depot then).